# extrapolate position of vehicle by adding new rows to tibbles

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have time `t`, speed `v` and position `x` of a vehicle along with other informations: `info1, info2, status`

How can I extend the tibble by linearly extrapolating the position based on last speed `(v = 14)` for given `timestamps`. So the added rows are copy of the last row except with the predicted positions and `status` changed to "predicted"`.

Is it possible to do it without using loop.

```
tbl <- tibble(info1 = rep("a", 3),
              info2 = rep("b", 3),
              t = c(1, 2, 3),
              v = c(12, 13, 14),
              x = c(12, 24, 37), 
              status = rep("real", 3))

timestamps <- c(4, 5, 6, 8) # timestamps does not linearly increase

# desired output
tbl_desired <- tibble(info1 = rep("a", 7),
                      info2 = rep("b", 7),
                      t = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8),
                      v = c(12, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14),
                      x = c(12, 24, 37, 51, 65, 79, 107), 
                      status = c(rep("real", 3), rep("predicted", 4)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditions are not clear especially the predicted values in 'x'.  Below code works in the following way

1. Extracts the last row (`slice_tail`, `n = 1`)
2. update the columns 't', 'v', 'x' (`summarise`)
3. Bind the rows from the original data (`bind_rows`)

```
library(dplyr)
tbl %>% 
   slice_tail(n = 1) %>% 
   summarise(info1, info2, t = timestamps, v = v, 
     x =  (x + cumsum(c(1, diff(t)) * 
      rep(last(v), length(t)))), status = 'predicted') %>% 
   bind_rows(tbl, .)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 6
  info1 info2     t     v     x status   
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
1 a     b         1    12    12 real     
2 a     b         2    13    24 real     
3 a     b         3    14    37 real     
4 a     b         4    14    51 predicted
5 a     b         5    14    65 predicted
6 a     b         6    14    79 predicted
7 a     b         8    14   107 predicted
```

---

If there are many columns, after `slice`ing the last row, use `mutate` to update only the columns that needs to be changed and wrap in a `list` whereever the `length` is greater than 1, then `unnest` the `list` column

```
library(tidyr)
tbl %>% 
   slice_tail(n = 1) %>%
   mutate(t = list(timestamps), v = v,
    x = list((x + cumsum(c(1, diff(timestamps)) * 
      rep(last(v), length(timestamps))))), status = 'predicted') %>% 
   unnest(where(is.list)) %>% 
   bind_rows(tbl, .)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 6
  info1 info2     t     v     x status   
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
1 a     b         1    12    12 real     
2 a     b         2    13    24 real     
3 a     b         3    14    37 real     
4 a     b         4    14    51 predicted
5 a     b         5    14    65 predicted
6 a     b         6    14    79 predicted
7 a     b         8    14   107 predicted
```

---

Or use `add_row` and then `fill` the `NA` rows with previous non-NA for those columns not specified in the `add_row`

```
library(tibble)
tbl %>% 
   add_row(t = timestamps, v = last(.$v), 
    x = (last(.$x) + cumsum(c(1, diff(timestamps)) * 
       rep(last(.$v), length(timestamps)))), status = 'predicted') %>% 
   fill(everything())
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 6
  info1 info2     t     v     x status   
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
1 a     b         1    12    12 real     
2 a     b         2    13    24 real     
3 a     b         3    14    37 real     
4 a     b         4    14    51 predicted
5 a     b         5    14    65 predicted
6 a     b         6    14    79 predicted
7 a     b         8    14   107 predicted
```

Comment: Thanks, I have over 50 columns (not just info1, info2). I could show in the example.  Is there a way to duplicate with out writing all columns.

Comment: @SiH Does the update works for you?  The columns to be changed can only be changed manually because the values are going to be different for those columns and the functions to be applied.

Comment: I am trying to repeat the steps but I am getting errors - I have 4 rows and I am adding 10 rows.<error/tibble_error_incompatible_new_cols>
New columns must be compatible with `.data`.
x New columns have 10 rows.
i `.data` has 4 rows.

Comment: @SiH I don't know about the errors.  All the solutions works on the data you provided.  i.e. I provided 3 solutions

Comment: @SiH The incompabile may be from a type issue which I couldn't reproduce from your data showed

Comment: Yes, thank you for that. I will try to fix it

Comment: @SiH Can you try the `add_row`, which should work

Comment: Yes, `add_row` worked, thanks